# When is the GUID partition table (GPT) preferred over Apple partition map (APM) for external drives?

Tags: external-disk, disk-format, hfs+, guid

I have seagate external portable hard-drive 1 TB, and I will be using with following Mac's.

13" White MacBook (Intel Core 2 Duo) running Snow Leopard
13" MacBook Air (Intel Core i5) running Lion
iMac running Lion

What partition map I should use, GUID or Apple when formatting external portable hard-drive?

Answer (score 5):

It's always better unless you must use the drive with an OS that is too old or too different to support the GPT format. Windows, Unix, macOS all support GPT / GUID and [APM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Partition_Map) is not widely supported on other OS.

To elaborate, GUID (or more properly [GPT - the **G**UID **p**artition **t**able scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table)) is the new bootable standard for Macs so use it unless you have macs that need to boot from this drive and cannot support GUID. [APM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Partition_Map) is your only option in that unlikely case. The vast majority of macs will work with both in all instances - especially if you don't need it to be bootable.